# invalid a href URL's

Tags: html, w3c-validation

For example, I have a URL, that someone entered into a specific CMS form field, to display on the website: http://seneca.sunyconnect.suny.edu:4730/F/?request=79396&func=find-b&find_code=sys&local_base=her01pub

and it outputs the following html:

```
<a href="http://seneca.sunyconnect.suny.edu:4730/F/?request=79396&func=find-b&find_code=sys&local_base=her01pub" title="The Sociology of Sports" rel="external">The Sociology of Sports</a>
```

It is not considered valid, with the warning message: unescaped & or unknown entity "&func", as well as another warning: unescaped & or unknown entity "&find_code"

I know func & find_code are elements being passed thru the URL, but is there a way to make it valid & still allow it to go to the correct destination?

Comment: What validator is complaining about it? I would guess that the problem is because you are passing the parameters to the directory which is using a default file (eg index.html, index.php, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `&amp;`:

```
<a href="http://seneca.sunyconnect.suny.edu:4730/F/?request=79396&amp;func=find-b&amp;find_code=sys&amp;local_base=her01pub" title="The Sociology of Sports" rel="external">The Sociology of Sports</a>
```

See [Ampersands (&'s) in URLs](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace any unescaped ampersands (&) with &amp;

Comment: Here you have the normative reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2